# Installing Xamarin fail on Mac due to Android SDK

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I'm trying to install Xamarin on my MacBook Pro 2011 running 10.7.4.
When I run the installer it attempts to install the Android SDK first, however after a while it fails and the error report states:

```
Error downloading from Google server. Android SDK.
The operation has timed out.
Exception type: System.Net.WebException
Message: The operation has timed out.
at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.Read (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.DownloadService.DoDownload (Int64 totalBytes, System.IO.Stream responseStream, System.IO.Stream outputStream, System.Object state) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Utilities.DownloadUrl (System.Net.HttpWebResponse response, System.String url, System.Action`4 doDownload, Boolean noCache, System.Object state) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

Android SDK installation failed with more than one exception (Attempt #Android SDK)
Some installation errors are present.
Exception type: System.AggregateException
Message: Some installation errors are present.
Exception type: Xamarin.Web.Installer.InstallException
Message: Download failed.
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.ValidateDownloadItem () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.AndroidSoftwareItem.Install (UInt32 tryNumber) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at MacInstaller.WizardPageInstallationController.InstallationWorker () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
Exception type: System.Net.WebException
Message: The operation has timed out.
at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.Read (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.DownloadService.DoDownload (Int64 totalBytes, System.IO.Stream responseStream, System.IO.Stream outputStream, System.Object state) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Utilities.DownloadUrl (System.Net.HttpWebResponse response, System.String url, System.Action`4 doDownload, Boolean noCache, System.Object state) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
Exception type: Xamarin.Web.Installer.InstallException
Message: Download failed.
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.ValidateDownloadItem () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.AndroidSoftwareItem.Install (UInt32 tryNumber) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at MacInstaller.WizardPageInstallationController.InstallationWorker () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
Exception type: System.Net.WebException
Message: The operation has timed out.
at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.Read (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.DownloadService.DoDownload (Int64 totalBytes, System.IO.Stream responseStream, System.IO.Stream outputStream, System.Object state) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Utilities.DownloadUrl (System.Net.HttpWebResponse response, System.String url, System.Action`4 doDownload, Boolean noCache, System.Object state) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
Exception type: Xamarin.Web.Installer.InstallException
Message: Download failed.
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.ValidateDownloadItem () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.AndroidSoftwareItem.Install (UInt32 tryNumber) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at MacInstaller.WizardPageInstallationController.InstallationWorker () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
Exception type: System.Net.WebException
Message: The operation has timed out.
at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.Read (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.DownloadService.DoDownload (Int64 totalBytes, System.IO.Stream responseStream, System.IO.Stream outputStream, System.Object state) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Utilities.DownloadUrl (System.Net.HttpWebResponse response, System.String url, System.Action`4 doDownload, Boolean noCache, System.Object state) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

What's wrong?

Comment: "Error downloading from Google server. Android SDK.  The operation has timed out."  Sounds like there is a connectivity issue on your end, or maybe theirs.